# Order By date Desc issue

Tags: sql, date, union

I have these queries:

```
(SELECT * FROM product WHERE var<>'0'ORDER BY date DESC)
```

and

```
(SELECT * FROM product WHERE var='0' ORDER BY date DESC).
```

When i try to unite the result from the two into one with

```
 (SELECT * FROM product WHERE var<>'0'ORDER BY date DESC) 
 UNION 
 (SELECT * FROM product WHERE var='0' ORDER BY date DESC)
```

The result lose the order by... the resulting set has first all the records with var not zero and then all the record with var zero but them are not ordered by date... Singularly the order is working... Why?
I tried to use a unique order by but the result mix the record having var equal or not to zero...

Comment: Are these just sample queries? Because the Union is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM product WHERE var IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx Example C

Comment: no these are the real queries, and are actually wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is order the result set putting `'0'` last, then order each subset by date. In that case you can forget the union and do this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE var IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CASE WHEN var = '0' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, date DESC
```

Comment: this is exactly what i meant to do... i've never seen this syntax before: what is the meaning of the clause "WHEN var = '0' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END". I mean, this selects all the products ordered by what?

Comment: It's actually `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <expr> [, ...] [ELSE <expr>] END`. In this case, if var is `'0'` it will return a 2, otherwise a 1. When ordering by this it will but the 1's first, then the 2's - selecting all products ordered by "whether it is '0' or not", then by date

Comment: Sagacious... Thank you very much! I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to apply the order last:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var<>'0'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var='0'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

**Edit** if you instead want to preserver the order in both parts, so first all with `var<>'0'` (internally ordered by `date DESC`) and then all with `var='0'` (internally ordered by `date DESC`):

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var<>'0'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var='0'
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN var<>'0' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
    date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var<>'0'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM product WHERE var='0'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM product
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: except when the `var` has Nulls.